# Fetch data from three tables where a particular column from other two tables are null?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: A, B and C.

Tables have the following columns:

```
A: id, name, shipdate
B: id, returndate
C: id, deliverydate
```

I have fetched data of Tables A and B using INNER JOIN and the ID Column.

```
SELECT  A.name, 
        A.shipdate, 
        B.returndate 
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
```

Same I have fetched data  of Tables A nd C using INNER JOIN AND ID column.

But how to fetch data from Tables A, B and C where returndate is null and deliverydate is null?

Here's the query i tried:

```
SELECT   A.name, 
         A.shipdate, 
         B.returndate, 
         C.deliverydate 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id 
INNER JOIN C ON A.id = C.id 
WHERE B.returndate = null 
AND C.deliverydate = null
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. I.e. show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) Also show us your current query.

Comment: LEFT JOIN rather than INNER join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using left join and IS NULL (= null won't find anything since null is <> to anything)

```
drop table if exists a,b,c;

create table a(id int, name varchar(3), shipdate date);
create table b(id int,returndate date);
create table c(id int,deliverydate date);

insert into a values(1,'aaa','2022-01-01'),(2,'bbb','2022-01-01'),(3,'ccc','2022-01-01'),(4,'ddd','2022-01-01');

insert into b values(1,'2022-01-01'),(2,'2022-01-01');

insert into c values(1,'2022-01-01'),(3,'2022-01-01');

SELECT A.name, A.shipdate, B.returndate, C.deliverydate 
FROM A 
left JOIN B ON A.id = B.id 
left JOIN C ON A.id = C.id 
WHERE B.returndate is null AND C.deliverydate is null;

+------+------------+------------+--------------+
| name | shipdate   | returndate | deliverydate |
+------+------------+------------+--------------+
| ddd  | 2022-01-01 | NULL       | NULL         |
+------+------------+------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just constrain your condition in `WHERE`:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
  ON A.id = B.id
INNER JOIN C
  ON B.id = C.id
WHERE 
  ISNULL(B.returndate) = 1 AND ISNULL(C.deliverydate) = 1
```

Instead of `ISNULL(B.returndate) = 1` you can use `B.returndate is null`, but a statement like `B.returndate = null` will always return `false`.

Comment: An inner join only returns where there is a match which is not what is required here.

Comment: @P.Salmon then also a left join is wrong and you have to use a full outer join

Comment: @dcolazin still its returning empty rows

Comment: @NitinRajan please state correctly your problem: if an id is only on table A, you want it returned? if so, use LEFT JOINs instead of INNER JOINs